# Is it safe to store milliseconds since Epoch in uint32

Tags: c++

I'm currently rewriting some old code and came across this:

```
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
unsigned int t = tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
```

This really looks like they're trying to store the milliseconds since Epoch in an uint32. And for sure I thought that this would not fit so I did some testing.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, nullptr);
    uint32_t t32 = tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
    int64_t t64 = tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

And I was kind of right:

```
(gdb) print t32
$1 = 1730323142
(gdb) print t64
$2 = 1423364498118
```

So I guess it's not safe what they're doing. But what are they doing and why are they doing this and what does actually happen? *(in this example 10 bits from the left will be lost, they only care about the diffs)* Do they still keep millisecond precision? *(yes)* Note they're sending this "timestamp" over network and still use it for calculation.

Comment: I would guess that the code you quote trying to produce a seed for a random number generator.

Comment: @HotLicks no it's not.

Comment: (One also needs to recall that `int` is not necessarily 32 bits.)

Comment: if it had been seconds and a signed int32 it would overflow around 2038. the unsigned doubles the time since 1970 to about 136 years, say 2106. then the milliseconds reduces that by a factor of a thousand, to about 0.136 years, I would guess that's somewhere in april 1970. for a better estimate use a calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not "safe": it sacrifices portability, accuracy, or both.

It is portable if you only care about the low bits, e.g. if you're sending these times on the network and then diffing them on the other side with a maximum difference of about four million seconds (46 days).

It is accurate if you only run this code on systems where `int` is 64 bits.  There are some machines like that, but not many.

Answer (score 2):

It is safer? I could answer no and yes. I said no because, at this day, we are using almost all bits (from an 32 bit number) to account the epoch since january, 1970. When you multiply by 1000 (dec) you are, almost, rotating all bit to left by something closer to 10 bits, which means losing precision.

I could say yes to your answer too. At the end of your question you said that this number is being used to taking account of the timestamp of packet in a network. The question is: How long is it time to live expect to wear off? 10 years? 10 days, 10 seconds? Losing 10 bits in precision of miliseconds will give you a large amount of time to do your calculations between two packets with precision of milisecond, which I guess is what you want

Comment: Where did you get the "timestamp of packet" idea?  The OP never said that.

Comment: Well he said that: "Note they're sending this "timestamp" over network and still use it for calculation."